# Apply RANK function to a set according to alphabetical order

Tags: mdx

Is it possible to create a measure that produces the rank of a set according to their alphabetical order i.e. Aleen should be 1 .... Zebedie should be ranked 101 (set has 101 items)

This does not work:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Alphabetic_Rank] AS 
    RANK(
        [CustomerName].CurrentMember,
        ORDER(
            [CustomerName],
            [CustomerName],
            ASC
            )
        )
```

---

**EDIT**

A further example of trying to apply this is the following which also does not work:

```
WITH 
SET [orderedSet] AS
    ORDER(
    [Operator].members,
    [Operator].currentmember.name,
    BASC
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[newMeasure] AS
    RANK(
    [orderedSet].currentmember, 
    [orderedSet].members
    )
SELECT
   {} ON COLUMNS,
   [orderedSet] 
   * 
   [Measures].[newMeasure] ON ROWS
FROM [ourCube]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the NAME as order's numerical value :

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Alphabetic_Rank] AS 
    RANK(
        [CustomerName].CurrentMember,
        ORDER(
            [CustomerName].members,
            [CustomerName].currentMember.NAME,
            BASC
            )
        )
```

EDIT for the second part :

```
WITH 
SET [orderedSet] AS
    ORDER(
    [Operator].members,
    [Operator].currentmember.name,
    BASC
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[newMeasure] AS
    RANK(
    [Operator].currentmember, 
    [orderedSet]
    )
SELECT
   [Measures].[newMeasure] ON COLUMNS,
   [orderedSet] ON ROWS
FROM [ourCube]
```

Comment: +1 thanks Mark ...spot on as usual: I've tried to take your logic and then apply it to a further example that I've edited into the OP - what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: thanks Marc ....how come changing `[orderedSet].members` to `[orderedSet]` as the second argumnet of the `RANK` function helps so much? Surely they are the same?

Comment: Not sure but I guess the issue was more about [ordereset].currentMember replaced by [Operator].currentMember - at least @icCube works that way - using the currentMember from the axis in that case.

Comment: thanks Marc - so from this is it ok to say that in `MDX` one cannot use `.members` or `.currentMember` against a custom `set` created in the `WITH` clause ?

Comment: also Marc - can I think of measures as tuples in MDX?

Comment: @whytheq At least in Analysis Services, `Members` can only be used on a "hierarchy expression" or a "level expression", and is a method converting from a hierarchy object type or level object type to the set object type (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144851.aspx). Sets are already sets, and need no type conversion.