# The 'Rank' dimension contains more than one hierarchy error

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Rank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [All Products].[Group 2].CurrentMember
     ,Order
      (
        [All Products].[Group 2].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[test]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Rank] ON COLUMNS
 ,[All Products].[Group 2].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [cube];
```

error: The 'Rank' dimension contains more than one hierarchy, therefore the hierarchy must be explicitly specified.
Execution complete

Comment: You may want to add more 'details' and 'explanation' about the problem and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to use `rank` is to order the set before hitting the rank function:

```
WITH 
  SET [OrderedGroup] AS
    Order
      (
        [All Products].[Group 2].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[test]
      )
  MEMBER [Rank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [All Products].[Group 2].CurrentMember
     ,[OrderedGroup] 
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Rank] ON COLUMNS
 ,[All Products].[Group 2].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [cube];
```

Here is a reference to a previous post I made concerning `Rank`:

[Apply RANK function to a set according to alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930593/apply-rank-function-to-a-set-according-to-alphabetical-order)